# Where do I initialize state in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm writing a simple class and trying to figure out where is the best place to initialize the state, should I do it in a constructor like this:

```
Class Quotes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: 'blue'
        };
   }
...
```

Or as a state property like this:

```
Class Quotes extends Component {
state = {
    color: 'blue'
  };
...
```

Which one is better practice? and what are the advantages and disadvantages of both?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct uses of initialising state. I would recommend to use constructor when you want to build a state using `props` otherwise go with other pattern.

```js
export default class Person extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: props.name || 'User',
    }
  }
}
```

When props is not required for initialization

```js
export default class Person extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    name: 'User',
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its good to initialize state inside constructor like so whenever your component is initializing it will give default state to component

```
Class Quotes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            color: 'blue'
        };
   }
}
```